# Volley seems to be too slow and inefficient

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I've been using volley for quite a while now. I noticed that my requests seem to be taking a lot of time. After debugging I figured out that for a single service request  logged a response time of

```
Volley  Request.finish: 7163 ms: [ ]
```

where as

```
HttpClient 3996ms (after JSONObject creation)
```

............................................................

And again on my second try run

```
Request.finish: 6918 ms: [ ] 

Httpclient 3670ms
```

I tried a number of times with just these two variants for the same request and found that volley takes twice as much time even when no other service/request are being made.

Futhurmore I Have set the retry policy for every request as

```
req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                40000,
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

inorder to disable multiple any multiple n/w io that may happen.

I feel that volley is grossly inefficient and slow or that I might be missing something. What could be the possible reason and which could be a faster http library other than having to use the stock option clubbed with the AsyncTask.

Comment: Check http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/

Comment: @ArkarAung : Thanks I've been consider switching to retrofit .But the benchmarks seems to have left me in a  bit of a pickle, I've run the test 5 times and repeatedly volley fared badly with respect to async(normal http client).

Comment: did you manage to get a solution for this thread?